# How to resolve the keyword error in the code?

Tags: python, error-handling, scipy

```
lrPAN = scipy.io.loadmat('E:\TEST_CODE_240519\Input.mat')
lrPAN_input = lrPAN["Input"]

hrPAN = scipy.io.loadmat('E:\TEST_CODE_240519\Target.mat')
hrPAN_input = hrPAN["Target"]

[patch_size, number_of_patches] = lrPAN_input.shape
Keyerror:lrPAN_input = lrPAN["Input"]

KeyError: 'Input'
```

Comment: Pls add more detail. Which's code language